# Subset rows with first observation after a given occurrence

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to accomplish the following:

1. group data by id
2. remove any rows after '3' occurs.
3. find the closest '1','2' or NA that precedes '3' and only keep that row.

My data:

```
data <- data.frame(
id=c(1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3), 
a=c(NA,1,2,3,3, NA,3,2,3, 1,5,3))
```

Desired output:

```
desired <- data.frame(
id=c(1,2,3), a=c(2,NA,1))
```

For steps 1-2, I have tried:

```
data %>% group_by(id) %>% slice(if(first(a) == 3))
```

but that seems quite off.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This breaks the problem into separate steps

```
data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(row_number()<first(which(a==3))) %>% # drop things past a 3
  filter(a %in% c(1,2,NA)) %>%                # only keep 1,2 or NA
  filter(row_number()==n())                   # choose the last row in each group
```